# calling a function which shows sub category list in a select box using observe function is working only first time

Tags: function, ipywidgets, global

> I have simple df have main category and its sub items. I made two select boxes to select main category and it automatically shows belonged items at the other select box using 'observe'
>   But it works only at the first time category selection and after I selected another category it didn't show sub items in an another select box.
>
> If i put 'observe' inside the 'def' the function is worked as I wanted.
>   But this approach is troublesome if I have many other 'def' executing on observe on change.
>   I am also looking for the way to make this code simple without using global.
>   And also welcome any ideas to make this code simpler and lighter.

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as wg
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
df_list=[{'Category':'fruit','name':['banana','apple','mango']},\
         {'Category':'animal','name':['lion','monkey','tiger','cat','dog']},\
         {'Category':'body','name':['eyes','hands','ears','arms']},\
         {'Category':'office','name':['table','computer','printer']}]
df=pd.DataFrame(df_list)

Category_box=wg.Select(options=list(df.Category),continuous_update=False,layout=Layout(width='30%'))
name_box=wg.Select(options=list(df[df['Category']==Category_box.value].name)[0],continuous_update=False,\
                   layout=Layout(width='30%'))
hbox=wg.HBox(children=[Category_box,name_box])
display(hbox)

def select_on_change(change):
    if change['name'] == 'value':
        global Category_box
        global name_box
        global hbox
        Category_box=wg.Select(options=list(df.Category),continuous_update=False,layout=Layout(width='30%'),value=Category_box.value)
        name_box=wg.Select(options=list(df[df['Category']==Category_box.value].name)[0],continuous_update=False,\
                   layout=Layout(width='30%'))
        hbox=wg.HBox(children=[Category_box,name_box])
        clear_output()
        display(hbox)
    #Category_box.observe(select_on_change)


Category_box.observe(select_on_change)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for the complete and clear example.

The solution is to not create new widgets in your function that you are observing. Instead just update the `.options` of your `name_box` widget. This way, no globals required.

```py
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as wg
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
df_list=[{'Category':'fruit','name':['banana','apple','mango']},\
         {'Category':'animal','name':['lion','monkey','tiger','cat','dog']},\
         {'Category':'body','name':['eyes','hands','ears','arms']},\
         {'Category':'office','name':['table','computer','printer']}]
df=pd.DataFrame(df_list)

Category_box=wg.Select(options=list(df.Category),continuous_update=False,layout=Layout(width='30%'))
name_box=wg.Select(options=list(df[df['Category']==Category_box.value].name)[0],continuous_update=False,\
                   layout=Layout(width='30%'))
hbox=wg.HBox(children=[Category_box,name_box])
display(hbox)

def select_on_change(change):
    if change['name'] == 'value':
        name_box.options = list(df[df['Category']==Category_box.value].name)[0]


Category_box.observe(select_on_change)
```

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer if it solved the issue?